# XNA C# Camera and model

Tags: c#, xna, camera, 3d-model

I have created 3 classes: one for the game, one for the model and one for the camera. I want my camera to follow my model as it moves, but my model is no longer appearing. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong in my camera and/or game class?

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace test1
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;



    //Visual components
    Ship ship = new Ship();
    Cam cam1 = new Cam();        




    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }      

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        ship.Model = Content.Load<Model>("Models/p1_wedge");
        ship.Transforms = cam1.SetupEffectDefaults(ship.Model);            
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed ||
            Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        // Get some input.
        UpdateInput();

        // Add velocity to the current position.
        ship.Position += ship.Velocity;
        cam1.cameraPosition += cam1.cameraTarget;
        // Bleed off velocity over time.
        ship.Velocity *= 0.95f;
        cam1.cameraTarget *= 0.95f;

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected void UpdateInput()
    {
        // Get the game pad state.
        GamePadState currentState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
        KeyboardState currentKeyState = Keyboard.GetState();

            ship.Update(currentState);
            cam1.Update(currentState);

            // In case you get lost, press A to warp back to the center.
            if (currentState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed || currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
            {
                ship.Position = Vector3.Zero;
                ship.Velocity = Vector3.Zero;
                ship.Rotation = 0.0f;                  
            }            
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        Matrix shipTransformMatrix = ship.RotationMatrix
                * Matrix.CreateTranslation(ship.Position);
        DrawModel(ship.Model, shipTransformMatrix, ship.Transforms);
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }


    public static void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix modelTransform,
Matrix[] absoluteBoneTransforms)
    {
        //Draw the model, a model can have multiple meshes, so loop
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            //This is where the mesh orientation is set
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.World =
                    absoluteBoneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                    modelTransform;
            }
            //Draw the mesh, will use the effects set above.
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
}
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;


namespace test1
{
class Ship
{
    public Model Model;
    public Matrix[] Transforms;

    //Position of the model in world space
    public Vector3 Position = Vector3.Zero;

    //Velocity of the model, applied each frame to the model's position
    public Vector3 Velocity = Vector3.Zero;
    private const float VelocityScale = 5.0f;

    public Matrix RotationMatrix =
 Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2);

    private float rotation;

    public float Rotation
    {
        get { return rotation; }
        set
        {
            float newVal = value;
            while (newVal >= MathHelper.TwoPi)
            {
                newVal -= MathHelper.TwoPi;
            }
            while (newVal < 0)
            {
                newVal += MathHelper.TwoPi;
            }

            if (rotation != value)
            {
                rotation = value;
                RotationMatrix =
                    Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation);
            }

        }
    }

    public void Update(GamePadState controllerState)
    {

        KeyboardState currentKeyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            Rotation += 0.10f;
        else
        // Rotate the model using the left thumbstick, and scale it down.
        Rotation -= controllerState.ThumbSticks.Left.X * 0.10f;

        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            Rotation -= 0.10f;

        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            Velocity += RotationMatrix.Forward * VelocityScale;
        else
        // Finally, add this vector to our velocity.
        Velocity += RotationMatrix.Forward * VelocityScale *
         controllerState.Triggers.Right;
    }  

}
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;


namespace test1
{
class Cam : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    public Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 2000.0f, 25000.0f);
    public Vector3 cameraTarget = Vector3.Zero;

   Matrix projectionMatrix;
    Matrix viewMatrix;

    protected override void Initialize(){

            projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
       MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f),
       GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.AspectRatio,
       20000.0f, 30000.0f);

        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition,
            cameraTarget, Vector3.Up);

        base.Initialize();            
    }

    public Matrix[] SetupEffectDefaults(Model myModel)
    {
        Matrix[] absoluteTransforms = new Matrix[myModel.Bones.Count];
        myModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(absoluteTransforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in myModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.Projection = projectionMatrix;
                effect.View = viewMatrix;
            }
        }
        return absoluteTransforms;
    }

    private const float VelocityScale = 5.0f;

    public Matrix RotationMatrix =
 Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2);

    private float rotation;

    public float Rotation
    {
        get { return rotation; }
        set
        {
            float newVal = value;
            while (newVal >= MathHelper.TwoPi)
            {
                newVal -= MathHelper.TwoPi;
            }
            while (newVal < 0)
            {
                newVal += MathHelper.TwoPi;
            }

            if (rotation != value)
            {
                rotation = value;
                RotationMatrix =
                    Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Update(GamePadState controllerState)
    {
        KeyboardState currentKeyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            Rotation += 0.10f;
        else
            // Rotate the model using the left thumbstick, and scale it down.
            Rotation -= controllerState.ThumbSticks.Left.X * 0.10f;

        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            Rotation -= 0.10f;

        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            cameraTarget += RotationMatrix.Forward * VelocityScale;
        else
            // Finally, add this vector to our velocity.
            cameraTarget += RotationMatrix.Forward * VelocityScale *
             controllerState.Triggers.Right;
    }
}
}
```

---

Comment: Do you really have that much whitespace and commented-out code in there?  Don't you find that unorganised and difficult to read/maintain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should learn how to organize your code, you created classes for each object but you still do some of the processing in each object and some in game, this is very messy!

The short answer to why your camera is not working, is simply because you are not using it!

You should follow a proper tutorial on creating a camera in XNA, like [this one](http://gamecamp.no/blogs/tutorials/archive/2008/01/29/creating-a-simple-xna-camera-class.aspx), but from looking briefly at your code, adding something like `cam1.SetupEffectDefaults(model);` in your `DrawModel` might be sufficient to have your `ViewMatrix` and `ProjectionMatrix` applied. Calling it in the init phase won't do much, as these matrices are updated during the game.

Comment: i was following that tut that you gave me and i got confused at:  this._camera = new Camera(graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport);
this._camera.LookAt = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);            where do i put that?

Comment: @steven the line right before these lines say `During construction of your game you initialize your camera`. With your code, I'd say it's in `public Game1()`, after creating the `graphics` object!

Comment: i keep getting test1.Game1 does not contain a definition for "_camera" and no extension method "_camera"

Comment: @steven that's because you need a `Camera _camera;` in your `Game1` class. If you're using the code from this tutorial, you should remove your `cam1`

Comment: thank you, would effect.View = this._camera.ViewMatrix;
effect.Projection = this._camera.ProjectionMatrix; also go in the draw method?

Comment: yes and no, this question has been answered by you but im getting a new error, could you have a look?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557592/xna-model-not-appearing-advice-needed