# xna model not appearing, advice needed

Tags: c#, xna

What I have:
game class
model class for my ship
Camera class

when I Press F5 my game opens, it shows blue, but my model doesnt appear, anyone got any advice for why this is happening?

if anyone would be able to help i would really thankful.

---

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

    namespace test1
    {
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;



    //Visual components
    Ship ship = new Ship();
    Camera _camera;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";


    }

   protected override void Initialize()
    {
        this.graphics.ToggleFullScreen(); 
        this._camera = new Camera(graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport);
        this._camera.LookAt = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);


        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        ship.Model = Content.Load<Model>("Models/p1_wedge");
        ship.Transforms = _camera.SetupEffectDefaults(ship.Model);


    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed ||
            Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        // Get some input.
        UpdateInput();



        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected void UpdateInput()
    {
        // Get the game pad state.
        GamePadState currentState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
        KeyboardState currentKeyState = Keyboard.GetState();

            ship.Update(currentState);

        }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        //camera
        this._camera.Update();

        _camera.LookAt = ship.Position;

        Matrix shipTransformMatrix = ship.RotationMatrix
                * Matrix.CreateTranslation(ship.Position);
        DrawModel(ship.Model, shipTransformMatrix, ship.Transforms);
        base.Draw(gameTime);

    }


    public static void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix modelTransform,
Matrix[] absoluteBoneTransforms)
    {
        //Draw the model, a model can have multiple meshes, so loop

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            //This is where the mesh orientation is set
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {

                effect.World =
                    absoluteBoneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                    modelTransform;
            }

            mesh.Draw();


        }
    }


}
    }
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;


namespace test1
{
class Ship
{
    public Model Model;
    public Matrix[] Transforms;

    //Position of the model in world space
    public Vector3 Position = Vector3.Zero;

    //Velocity of the model, applied each frame to the model's position
    public Vector3 Velocity = Vector3.Zero;
    private const float VelocityScale = 5.0f;

    public Matrix RotationMatrix =
 Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2);

    private float rotation;

    public float Rotation
    {
        get { return rotation; }
        set
        {
            float newVal = value;
            while (newVal >= MathHelper.TwoPi)
            {
                newVal -= MathHelper.TwoPi;
            }
            while (newVal < 0)
            {
                newVal += MathHelper.TwoPi;
            }

            if (rotation != value)
            {
                rotation = value;
                RotationMatrix =
                    Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation);
            }

        }
    }

    public void Update(GamePadState controllerState)
    {

        KeyboardState currentKeyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            Rotation += 0.10f;
        else
        // Rotate the model using the left thumbstick, and scale it down.
        Rotation -= controllerState.ThumbSticks.Left.X * 0.10f;

        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            Rotation -= 0.10f;

        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            Velocity += RotationMatrix.Forward * VelocityScale;
        else
        // Finally, add this vector to our velocity.
        Velocity += RotationMatrix.Forward * VelocityScale *
         controllerState.Triggers.Right;

        // In case you get lost, press A to warp back to the center.
        if  (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
        {
            Position = Vector3.Zero;
            Velocity = Vector3.Zero;
            Rotation = 0.0f;

        }

        Position += Velocity;
        Velocity *= 0.95f;
    }



}
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace test1
{
public class Camera
{

    private Vector3 _position;
    private Vector3 _lookAt;
    private Matrix _viewMatrix;
    private Matrix _projectionMatrix;
    private float _aspectRatio;


public Camera(Viewport viewport)
{
    this._aspectRatio = ((float)viewport.Width) / ((float)viewport.Height);
    this._projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                                MathHelper.ToRadians(40.0f),
                                this._aspectRatio,
                                20000.0f,
                                30000.0f);
}
public Vector3 Position
{
    get { return this._position; }
    set { this._position = value; }
}
public Vector3 LookAt
{
    get { return this._lookAt; }
    set { this._lookAt = value; }
}
public Matrix ViewMatrix
{
    get { return this._viewMatrix; }
}
public Matrix ProjectionMatrix
{
    get { return this._projectionMatrix; }
}
public void Update()
{
    this._viewMatrix = 
        Matrix.CreateLookAt(this._position, this._lookAt, Vector3.Up);

}

public Matrix[] SetupEffectDefaults(Model myModel)
{
    Matrix[] absoluteTransforms = new Matrix[myModel.Bones.Count];
    myModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(absoluteTransforms);

    foreach (ModelMesh mesh in myModel.Meshes)
    {
        foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
        {
            effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
            effect.Projection = ProjectionMatrix;
            effect.View = ViewMatrix;
        }
    }
    return absoluteTransforms;
}

}
}
```

---

**EDIT**

```
public static void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix modelTransform, 
Matrix[] absoluteBoneTransforms)
{
//Draw the model, a model can have multiple meshes, so loop
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
{
    //This is where the mesh orientation is set
    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
    {
        effect.World = 
            absoluteBoneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * 
            modelTransform;
        effect.Projection = _camera.ProjectionMatrix;
        effect.View = _camera.ViewMatrix; 
    }


    //Draw the mesh, will use the effects set above.
    mesh.Draw();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 issues with your code:

**Look At** You don't seem to update the Look At of your camera to point towards your spaceship, either make your camera "track" the spaceship by giving it a reference to it and in your `Update` update the look at position or manually update the lookat position from your `Game1`.

**View / Projection Matrix** Even though your camera has a view matrix and a projection matrix, you don't use them in your `DrawModel`. When you assign your world, consider adding the two following lines

```
effect.Projection = _camera.ProjectionMatrix;
effect.View = _camera.ViewMatrix;
```

Comment: im still a bit new to this, could you maybe give me abit more advice on doing so? and when i add the 2 effects i get An object reference is required for the nonstatic field

Comment: @steven in your update I would put something like `_camera.LookAt = ship.Position;`. Can you copy paste the lines you added (or update the code in your question)?

Comment: @steven I just realized your `DrawModel` is static, there's no reason for it to be static, just remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: darn, thanks for the help but its still not showing my model :( this is a tough one :(

Comment: @steven without having the code / assets it's really hard to "debug", I don't think I can do much more unfortunately... :/

Comment: i know how you feel, iv hit a wall too :( but iv uploaded the project to http://www.speedyshare.com/6FUdN/test1.rar you would be hero if you dont mind having a look?

Comment: @steven alright, I'll see what I can do, I don't have XNA on this computer, I'll try to debug your software either later tonight or tomorrow

Comment: @steven which version of visual studio did you use? Visual C# 2010 Express Edition?

Comment: Visual studio 2010 ulitmate, xna 4.0

Comment: Still haven't had time to set up, will do tonight

Comment: @steven I was about to check your problem but I see you accepted an answer, I will assume it fixed your problem

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly several issues in your code preventing it from working as expected. The two that pop out at me is that 1.) you never set the camera position so it defaults to 0,0,0 which colocates it with the ship model. So your camera is actually inside the model and any triangle that is in it's view would be culled as a backside triangle if 2.) it wasn't already frustrum culled since your nearplane is set to 20000.